# power of 2 walks of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given graph $G= \langle V,E\rangle$ where $|V|=n$, if G is Cycle then the number of $n$ walks for each vertex is $2^n$ because at any point in the walk you can only move left or right.

Is there any other graph G that have the same number of walks as cycle graphs ?

I mean if the graph has $n$ vertices then each vertex have $2^n$ walks starting from that vertex, and somewhat related if it can have $2^m$ for $m$ not necessarily equal to $n$ ?

I suspect the cycle graph are the only such graphs, i might be wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Path graph have only power of $2$ walks, but they are different for different vertices so this does not count!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycle graphs are the only connected graphs satisfying a stronger condition: for all $k$, the number of walks of length $k$ starting from any vertex is $2^k$. (Graphs with multiple connected components which are all cycles will also satisfy this condition.)

We have more flexibility if we only want the number of walks of length $n$ from any vertex to be $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices.  For example, the following graph will work:

```
   1        6
   |        |
2--0--4  7--5--9
   |        |
   3        8
```

In each component, all walks must alternate between vertices of degree $4$ (vertices $0$ or $5$) and vertices of degree $1$ (the others). At each vertex of degree $4$, there are $4$ options for the next step; at each vertex of degree $1$, there is only one option. After $10$ steps (the number of vertices), we will have left a degree-$4$ vertex exactly $5$ times, which means there are $4^5 = 2^{10}$ possible walks we could have taken. (This will work for walks of any even length; we need two components in order to make $n$ even. A graph with any even number of components, all of which have this same structure, will also work.)

Are there any *connected* graphs with this property, other than the cycle? Well, we can make a few deductions:

- If the graph were to *contain* a cycle, then a vertex on that cycle would have $2^n$ walks of length $n$ contained within that cycle alone, so there could not be any walks that left the cycle. This can only happen if the graph *is* the cycle. So all remaining examples must be acyclic: they must be trees.
- Trees, in particular, have a vertex of degree $1$. Let $x$ be such a vertex, $y$ its only neighbor, and $z$ an arbitrary neighbor of $y$. Then the number of walks of length $n$ starting at $x$ is equal to the number of walks of length $n$ starting at $z$ and continuing to $y$. Therefore there cannot be a walk of length $n$ starting at $z$ and going anywhere else: $z$ also has degree $1$.
- Now we know our graph must be a star, like what we see above: a central vertex with $n-1$ neighbors of degree $1$. The number of walks of length $n$ in this graph is $(n-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ starting from a degree-$1$ vertex, and $(n-1)^{\lceil n/2\rceil}$ starting from the central vertex. These are only equal if $n$ is even, but then $(n-1)^{n/2}$ is odd, so it cannot be a power of $2$.

Therefore the $n$-cycle is the only $n$-vertex connected graph such that from any vertex, there are $2^n$ walks of length $n$.

---

If we want the number of walks of length $n$ to be $2^m$ for every vertex, but the value of $m$ does not matter, then there are many more options. Any graph that is $2^k$-regular for any $k$ will have $(2^k)^n = 2^{kn}$ walks of length $n$, and there are many examples of such graphs.

Comment: Great answer, is there a link to a proof that cycles are the only connected graphs with walks of same power of $2$ ?

Comment: If that's true for all $k$, then it's true in particular for $k=1$, so the graph must be $2$-regular, and then it's forced to be a cycle.

Comment: yes but this is for the strong condition, how to be sure that the nth walks for every vertex is not $2^n$ and just the nth walk ?, I am not that good in graph theory

Comment: We know that if such graph exists then it must have some vertices with edges bigger than 2 and others with degree 1 otherwise it be bigger than $2^n$ if all degrees are bigger or equal $2$.

Comment: I've added a proof that it can only be the cycle.